# How to add export statements to bash_profile with Augeas and Puppet

Tags: puppet, augeas

I have Puppet + Augeas working to assign variable values in a bash_profile, however I have not found a way to export the variables from the file.

```
  augeas { "bash_profile-${user}-${name}":
    incl    => "/home/${user}/.bash_profile",
    lens    => 'Shellvars.lns',
    changes => "set ${variable_name} '\"${literal_value}\"'",
  }
```

Results in:

```
# .bash_profile 
variable="value"
```

But what i need is:

```
# .bash_profile 
export variable="value"
# or
variable="value"
export variable
```

This [Puppet ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1740) seems like it should point in the right direction, but I can't make out how to write the export statements

Comment: Have you considered managing the file directly with a `.erb` providing the content?

Comment: I would, but there is existing content I don't want to overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
  augeas { "bash_profile-${user}-${name}":
    incl    => "/home/${user}/.bash_profile",
    lens    => 'Shellvars.lns',
    changes => [
      "set ${variable_name} '\"${literal_value}\"'",
      "set ${variable_name}/export ''",
      ],
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Augeasproviders](https://augeasproviders.com) project has a [`shellvar` type](https://forge.puppet.com/herculesteam/augeasproviders_shellvar) for that:

```
shellvar { "bash_profile-${user}-${name}":
  ensure   => exported,
  target   => "/home/${user}/.bash_profile",
  variable => $variable_name,
  value    => $literal_value,
}
```

There are also options to manage quoting or array values.

Comment: Very nice - I will have a look at these next time